# regex to replace optional underscore

Tags: regex, linux, shell

I need to strip an underscore optionally if it exists.

```
string VIEW VXABC expected result VIEW ABC
string VIEW V_XABC expected result VIEW ABC
```

This is my try but results are eluding me

```
echo "VIEW VXABC" |sed 's/VIEW V_?X/VIEW ABC/'
VIEW VXABC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[me@home]$ echo VIEW V_XABC | sed -r 's/VIEW V_?X/VIEW /' 
VIEW ABC
[me@home]$ echo VIEW VXABC | sed -r 's/VIEW V_?X/VIEW /' 
VIEW ABC
```

Note the `-r` option. From the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
-r, --regexp-extended
    use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether this helps.

```
 sed -e 's/\(VIEW \)V[_X]\+\(ABC\)/\1 \2/'
testing
testing
VIEW VXABC
VIEW  ABC
VIEW V_XABC
VIEW  ABC
```

Comment: Yes this works too can you please elaborate what your regex does

Comment: **\(\)** is for capturing. **[]** is character class. **\+** is one or more of previous token.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and yes your answer is not only correct but educative wish i could pick up both the answers

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "extended regex" switch `-E`:

```
echo "VIEW VXABC" | sed -E 's/VIEW V_?X/VIEW ABC/'
```

From man page of `sed`:

> -E, -r, --regexp-extended
>
> use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use
>   POSIX -E)

Comment: Just a small thing - the above gets you VIEW ABCABC - if you are looking to just strip the V_?X echo "VIEW VXABC" | sed -E 's/V_?X//'

Comment: echo VIEW V_XABC | sed -e 's/VIEW V_?X/VIEW ABC/'
VIEW V_XABC nor this

Comment: Capital 'E'? What shell are you using?  it should't make a difference but... I'm using BASH and this is my output: $>echo "VIEW VXABC" | sed -E 's/V_?X//'
--> VIEW ABC

Comment: echo VIEW V_XABC | sed -e 's/VIEW V(\_)?X/VIEW ABC/'
VIEW V_XABC

Comment: echo "VIEW VXABC" | sed -E 's/VIEW V_?X/VIEW ABC/'
sed: invalid option -- E i am using bash and i dont have the capital E option in my version of sed